# MuseJSAssert: Error calling selector function:TypeError: this.elem.get(...) is undefined

Tags: javascript, adobe, muse

We are receiving the message below when visiting this landing page: http://elpasounited.com/

On FireFox: "MuseJSAssert: Error calling selector function:TypeError: this.elem.get(...) is undefined"

On Goole Chrome: "MuseJSAssert: Error calling selector function:TypeError: Cannot read property 'currentStyle' of undefined"

I tried adding, but did not work:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js"></script>
```

This website was built in Adobe Muse which has been deprecated for a while, but we just started receiving this message about two months ago. I'm not a JS developer, any ideas on how I can troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0):

You script src path doesn't exist.
I have checked [the link](http://musecdn2.businesscatalyst.com/scripts/4.0/jquery-1.8.3.min.js) its not available

[image]

And please choose the respected version number from this cdn

https://code.jquery.com/jquery/

You have a problem with 1.8.3
so try this one

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-YcbK69I5IXQftf/mYD8WY0/KmEDCv1asggHpJk1trM8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

please add this script on top of the other script

Comment: Tried your recommendations in different variations and none worked.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/svNeB.png may be you have error in JSON please check console.log